# JQuery video scrubber flicker in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, video, repaint, requestanimationframe

So I'm trying to implement a video that scrubs based on the scroll position of a page. I found a set up for it here: http://www.emergeinteractive.com/demos/javascript-video-scrubber/

Basically, a video is converted into an image sequence, loaded into an image array, and then the source of an image tag (or in my version a background-image) is updated based on the percentage of the scrollTop.

Here's a basic demo: https://room-dev-dxh.squarespace.com/home

The js looks like this:

```
var step = 1; // visible frame
var targetStep = 1; // frame to animate to
var images = new Array; 
var totalFrames = 263; // the number of images in the sequence of JPEG files

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){ 
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
      window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
      window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
      function( callback ){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
})();

(function animloop(){
  requestAnimFrame(animloop);
  targetStep = Math.max( Math.round( getYOffset() / 30 ) , 1 ); // what frame to animate to
  if(targetStep != step ) { step += (targetStep - step) / 5; } //     increment the step until we arrive at the target step
  changeFrame();
})();

function changeFrame() {
    var thisStep = Math.round(step); // calculate the frame number
    if(images.length > 0 && images[thisStep]) { // if the image exists in the array
    if(images[thisStep].complete) { // if the image is downloaded and ready
        $('#video').attr('src',images[thisStep].src); // change the source of our placeholder image
        }
    }
}

function getYOffset() { // get distance scrolled from the top
    var pageY;
    if(typeof(window.pageYOffset)=='number') {
        pageY=window.pageYOffset;
    }else{
        pageY=document.documentElement.scrollTop; // IE
    }
    return pageY;
}

function pad(number, length) { // pad numbers with leading zeros for JPEG sequence file names
    var str = '' + number; while (str.length < length) { str = '0' + str; }     return str;
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        <!--//

        totalFrames = 263; // the number of images in the sequence of JPEG files (this could be calculated server-side by scanning the frames folder)

        $(document).ready(function() {
            resizeAdjustments(); // adjust the size of video placeholder image to fit the screen and keep aspect ratio (zoom crop)
        });

        //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="resizeAdjustments();" onresize="resizeAdjustments();" onorientationchange="resizeAdjustments();">

    <!-- placeholder image for video (required) -->
    <img id="video" src="/assets/frames/image_000000.jpg" alt="" />

    <!-- preload the video frames (required) -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--//
        // image filenames in frames folder should be "image_000000.jpg" through "image_000098.jpg"
        for(i = 0; i < totalFrames; i++) { // loop for each image in sequence
            images[i] =  new Image(); // add image object to array
            images[i].src = "/assets/frames/image_"+pad(i, 6)+".jpg"; // set the source of the image object
        }
        //-->
    </script>
</body>
```

Right now this is working pretty well in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox 38/Mac/PC it flickers like crazy. I've been reading a lot about Firefox repaint rates, requestAnimationFrame, image preloading, opening in SafeMode on FF, but it's a persistent little bug. So my two main questions are:

1. Is there a way to modify this current code to work better in Firefox?
2. Is there an alternate way to achieve the same effect, possibly by scrubbing a webm video rather than a jpeg sequence? I've been struggling to find an example of someone else using this feature without scroll hijacking the page.

Many thanks!